No RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding on Red Hat 8
I'm not versed in cryptography and am pulling my hair out. I have the following (simplified) setup and code.
Maven setup to use BouncyCastle
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk18on</artifactId>
    <version>1.78.1</version>
</dependency>

Code
try {
    PublicKey serverPubKey = CertUtil.getPubKey(new File(cert_fp));
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding");
    OAEPParameterSpec specs = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
    cipher.init(1, serverPubKey, specs);
} catch (CertificateException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException |
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    LOGGER.severe("Cannot create encryption cipher.  " + e);
}

When running on Windows (Java 17), it works. When running on Red Hat 8 (openjdk 17), I got
Cannot create encryption cipher.  java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding

The thing is it used to work on Red Hat too. I'm a bit lost on what might caused the error now. I checked the command for running it and bouncycastle is in the classpath.
I added some codes to check the providers and it looks the same on both Windows and Linux.
Set<String> algs = new TreeSet<>();
    for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders()) {
    provider.getServices().stream()
            .filter(s -> "Cipher".equals(s.getType()))
            .map(Service::getAlgorithm)
            .forEach(algs::add);
}
algs.forEach(System.out::println);

Output
AES/CBC/NoPadding
AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
AES/CTR/NoPadding
AES/ECB/NoPadding
AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding
AES/GCM/NoPadding
AES_128/CBC/NoPadding
AES_128/ECB/NoPadding
AES_128/GCM/NoPadding
AES_192/CBC/NoPadding
AES_192/ECB/NoPadding
AES_192/GCM/NoPadding
AES_256/CBC/NoPadding
AES_256/ECB/NoPadding
AES_256/GCM/NoPadding
ARCFOUR
ChaCha20-Poly1305
DES/CBC/NoPadding
DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
DES/ECB/NoPadding
DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding
DESede/CBC/NoPadding
DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding
DESede/ECB/NoPadding
DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding
PBEWithHmacSHA1AndAES_128
PBEWithHmacSHA1AndAES_256
PBEWithHmacSHA224AndAES_128
PBEWithHmacSHA224AndAES_256
PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128
PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256
PBEWithHmacSHA384AndAES_128
PBEWithHmacSHA384AndAES_256
PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_128
PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_256
RSA/ECB/NoPadding
RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding

What am I missing? What can I try? I do have to use "RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding".
Thanks

What version of Java are you using? Also, try with OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding.

I am using openjdk 17.
I tried OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding and still get the NoSuchAlgorithmException.

For some reason the SunJCE provider does not seem to be available. Try to add the BouncyCastle provider: Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()); like here https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/16Ld.

That is it. That is the subtle part that I lost in the code. Thanks very much. I don't know how to set your comment as the answer though.

I had planned to setup a Virtualbox VM with RHEL8 to test this but I could not figure out how to do so without supplying Redhat with an inordinate amount of personal information.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk LOL. It did work out. I accidentally deleted the code that adds the BouncyCastleProvider. It works after I added it back. I agree with you that cipher type should have been included with the JRE comes with RH.

You need to explicitly register the Bouncy Castle crypto provider when your application starts, eg:
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

It  definitely includes "RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding".

The Bouncycastle provider should not be necessary at all.
